# JavaScript gl-matrix lib: how to get Euler angles from quat and quat from angles?

Tags: javascript, math, euler-angles

Is is possible using gl-matrix library? (Euler angles, I mean: pitch, yaw, roll)
( https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix )
Looked for in in command reference but found nothing useful.

Another realization for JavaScript would be useful as well.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com/search?q=euler+angle+quaternion+conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm for converting quaternion rotations to Euler angle rotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031005/is-there-an-algorithm-for-converting-quaternion-rotations-to-euler-angle-rotatio)

Comment: Which version of Euler angles? There are about 19 I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xyz type Euler angle:

```js
function toEulerXYZ(quat: quat) {
  const w = quat[3];
  const x = quat[0];
  const y = quat[1];
  const z = quat[2];

  const wx = w * x,
    wy = w * y,
    wz = w * z;
  const xx = x * x,
    xy = x * y,
    xz = x * z;
  const yy = y * y,
    yz = y * z,
    zz = z * z;

  const xyz = [
    -Math.atan2(2 * (yz - wx), 1 - 2 * (xx + yy)),
    Math.asin(2 * (xz + wy)),
    -Math.atan2(2 * (xy - wz), 1 - 2 * (yy + zz)),
  ];
  return xyz.map((x) => (x * 180) / Math.PI);
}
```

If other types, maybe refer to others, like [Quatenion.js](https://github.com/rawify/Quaternion.js/blob/master/quaternion.js#L890C33-L891C1)

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)