# JavaScript gl-matrix: quaternion from mat4

Tags: javascript, math

I'm using gl-matrix lib ( https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix ) 
There is a possibility to create mat3 from quat and quat from mat3:

- mat3.fromQuat
- quat.fromMat3

But I have mat4 rotation matrix.
I create it this way:

```
var turnmat = mat4.create();
mat4.identity(turnmat);

mat4.rotate(turnmat,turnmat, yaw,   [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.rotate(turnmat,turnmat, pitch, [1, 0, 0]);
mat4.rotate(turnmat,turnmat, roll,  [0, 0, 1]);
```

And then I want quat from this matrix. But there is only quat.fromMat3, not quat.fromMat4.
What do I do wrong here?

refs (no rep to add as links):

http:// glmatrix.net/docs/2.2.0/symbols/mat3.html#.fromQuat

http:// glmatrix.net/docs/2.2.0/symbols/quat.html#.fromMat3

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript gl-matrix lib: how to get Euler angles from quat and quat from angles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955358/javascript-gl-matrix-lib-how-to-get-euler-angles-from-quat-and-quat-from-angles)

Answer (score 0):

The quaternions as defined in gl-matrix are for 3D spaces only. What you want to do is to get the 3D rotation component out of your Mat4 and convert that to a quaternion.